# Does having two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths imply having a Hamiltonian circuit?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose a simple graph G has two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths, can we construct a Hamiltonian circuit in G?
 If no, can anyone provide a counterexample?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any thoughts on whether it should be possible or not?

Comment: Presumably the graph is simple, in that multiple edges (and loops) are disallowed? Otherwise the result is trivially false. :-)

Comment: We only consider sample graphs. I believe my statement is true since I’ve tried many different examples and they all have Hamiltonian circuits. However, I am not able to come up with a formal proof. I think we can use Dirac theory but I’m not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be paths with vertex set
$V=V(P_1)=V(P_2)=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8,v_9,v_{10},v_{11}\}$ and edge sets
$E(P_1)=\{v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_5,v_5v_6,v_6v_7,v_7v_8,v_8v_9,v_9v_{10},v_{10}v_{11}\}$ and $E(P_2)=\{v_1v_3,v_3v_5,v_5v_2,v_2v_4,v_4v_6,v_6v_8,v_8v_{10},v_{10}v_7,v_7v_9,v_9v_{11}\}.$

In the graph $G=P_1\cup P_2,\ P_1$ and $P_2$ are edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths with the same endpoints. The graph $G$ has no Hamiltonian circuit, since $G-v_6$ is disconnected.

[[image: The graph <span class=]$G$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FWS2.png)

Comment: You could also just say to join two copies of $K_5$ at one vertex.